# How to automate new gmail UI to send email by using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, ide, gmail

The current gmail UI has changed, it opens in a pop up DIV and the ID parameters are changing for each new compose window. Can anyone try to give me the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do all using XPath (find using `By.xpath("xpath expression")`):

- Open the gmail page
- Login as usual
- Click on compose button (its XPath expression: `"//div[text()='COMPOSE']"`)
- (The email dialog will pop up)
- Type (send keys) the addesses in the "To" text area: `"//textarea[@name='to']"`
- Type (send keys) the subject to the "Subject" input: `"//input[@name='subjectbox']"`
- Type (send keys) the email content to the editable div: `"//div[@class='gmail_default']"` (or `"//div[@aria-label='Message Body']"`), as it seems they changed their HTML recently)
- Hit send: `"//div[text()='Send']"`

Comment: Thanks for this acdcjunior, but the content box is served by iframe and the class got changed to "class=class=editable LW-avf". Anyhow, this is similar to what I found myself. Actually I was facing a bit problem in locating the element for TO field. But its solved now.

Comment: @MCKiran alright, great! But you do know how to get the elements via XPath, right? It'll make you life a lot easier with webdriver.

Comment: Great answer!, How to add an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

I found the below solution:

< tr>

```
<td>setTimeout</td>
<td>3000</td>
<td></td>
```

< /tr >

< !--open command usually waits for 30 secs, so we are now asking it to wait for only 3 secs-->

< tr>

```
<td>open</td>
<td>/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox?compose=new</td>
<td></td>
```

< /tr>

< tr>

```
<td>type</td>
<td>//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/textarea</td>
<td>McKiran@example.com</td>
```

< /tr>

< tr>

```
<td>type</td>
<td>name=subjectbox</td>
<td>Test</td>
```

< /tr>

< tr>

```
<td>type</td>
<td>class=editable LW-avf</td>
<td>Hi All<br/>Hope the test is successful. <br/><br/><i> Lovingly, </i></br><b>McKiran.</b></td>
```

< /tr>

< tr>

```
<td>click</td>
<td>class=T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3</td>
<td></td>
```

< /tr>

Answer (score 0):

**Use selenium webdrier**

go throw the below link

http://ngowda.blogspot.in/2014/01/uploading-file-in-e-commerce-site-using.html

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\Selenium\SeleniumWork\seleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/#identifier");
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']")).isEnabled())
        {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("youremailid");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='password']")); 
        if(menu.isEnabled())
        {

```
        System.out.println("Hello world");
         menu.sendKeys("emailidpassword");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signIn']")).click();
    }
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='to']")).sendKeys("@gmail.com");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='subjectbox']")).sendKeys("Sample");
```

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Message Body']")).sendKeys("HI this is simple message");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Send']")).click();

}

Comment: Please format your code and add an explanation to as why your provided code works. Thanks!