# Selenium gmail .. Type text in body

Tags: automation, gmail, selenium-ide

I am new to selenium and would like to send an email using gmail... I am aware if the automation policy of Google and will be using this mainly for testing and sending email to small number of friends , so please don't answer with ' it violates policy so don't do it ..'  Etc

I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135329) but its not working. The body of email is written as HTML div in body of email rather than `textarea`.

Can someone give me xpath , command , and value fields.

I would also like to know why the example given is not working as I am unable to understand it.

I am using https://mail.Google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm  to directly compose mail rather than the compose dialogue of email.

Answer (score 1):

After login please use Thread.sleep(10000) and then fine element as per below :

```
        //DO LOGIN

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        driver.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1");

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        //XPATH FOR BODY
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':nz']")).sendKeys("TEST DATA IN BODY");
```

I have tested and above code is working. Actually after login it takes some time to load so elements are not always visible immediately so I have used thred.sleep();

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I don't love it.

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=:om</td>
    <td>some@email.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=:p1</td>
    <td>subject text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>//input[@name='body']</td>
    <td>fdhh</td>
</tr>
```